# Java get the last added entry in map

Tags: java

I have a map that will be filled in a matter of time. problem is I want to know what the last added entry is. so far I only found the last entry in the map. is there a way to get the last added entry?

code so far:

```
        int spawned = 0;
     NavigableMap<String, Integer> minioncounter = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();

    while (spawned < 7) {
        if(!minioncounter.containsKey("big")){
            minioncounter.put("big", 1);
        }else if(!minioncounter.containsKey("small")){
            minioncounter.put("small", 1);
        }else if(minioncounter.containsKey("small") && minioncounter.get("small")  < 2){
            minioncounter.put("small", 2);
        }else if(!minioncounter.containsKey("archer")){
            minioncounter.put("archer", 1);
        }else{
            minioncounter.put("archer", minioncounter.get("archer")+1);
        }
        spawned++;  
        System.out.println(minioncounter.);
        System.out.println(minioncounter);

}
```

Current console output:

```
{big=1}
{big=1, small=1}
{big=1, small=2}
{archer=1, big=1, small=2}
{archer=2, big=1, small=2}
{archer=3, big=1, small=2}
{archer=4, big=1, small=2}
```

the order in which it is already stated is the one I have to use later on.

Comment: You could use a linked hash map

Answer (score 4):

See [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html).

This `Map` implementation maintains keys in the order in which they were inserted (basically). That said, this may not meet your *specific* needs, I'd read the documentation.

It's simple enough to extend an existing implementation to provide even more control, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own StoreLastAddMap class that wraps the real NavigableMap.  You expose the put method in your class where you will update the reference to the last added entry before calling the wrapped NavigableMap's add method.

```
public class StoreLastAddMap () {

    NavigableMap<String, Integer> minioncounter = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
    private String lastAddedKey;

    put(String key, Integer val) {
        lastAddedKey = key;
        minioncounter.put(key, val);
    }

    //getter for the wrapped Map to do other Map related stuff
    NavigableMap getMap() {return minioncounter;}

    Integer getLastAddedVal(){return minioncounter.get(lastAddedKey);}

    String getLastAddedKey() {return lastAddedKey;}
}
```

Or something to that affect.

Comment: I'd probably just extend `TreeMap<K, V>`, override `put` to record `lastAddedKey`, and add method `K getLastAddedKey`.

Comment: I was going to suggest that but didn't want to get down voted for suggesting inheritance over composition.